# How to update a label which gets value from an array.count?

Tags: swift, multithreading

So, I have a map with annotations which represent stands. Every stand has a list of bikes. I want to display the stand with the bikes in it. Currently, what happens is that evert annotation shows the values of bikes.count for every stand and it should show it only for one stand - the stand it represents on the map.

Here is my code:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "update")

    queue.async {

        var available = ""
        var nrOfAvailable = ""
        for s in self.fietshare.stands{
            for b in s.bikes {
                available = available + "id:" + String(s.id) +  "Nr:" + String( s.bikes.count) // shows too big numbers
                nrOfAvailable = String(b.distance) + "M"

                print(s.id)
                print("Nr of bikes")
                print(s.bikes.count)
            }
        }

        // UPDATE UI after all calculations have been done
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            lbAvailable.text = available
            nrOfAvailables.text = nrOfAvailable
          //  annotationView.layoutIfNeeded()

         //   self.view.backgroundColor = . black;
         //   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `available` is declared outside of the array and it sums up all the available values within the array.  So you need to get the value of the given stand while you are updating the `lblAvailable`.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't really grasp it.

Comment: You are summing up the value of available within the loop of the array.  Your question is that it should reflect the value of each stand. Since you have summed it up for all the stands, it would not reflect for each stand.